# Watir-webdriver: Chrome unhandled error on site where IE and Firefox working fine

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, watir, watir-webdriver

So I think this might be an error with the ChromeDriver but wanted to ask here first.

I'm having trouble using just about every webdriver function with chrome, yet IE and Firefox is working fine.

The site is www.bing.com's sign in with Windows live site.

https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=11&ct=1314808262&rver=6.0.5286.0&wp=MBI&wreply=http:%2F%2Fwww.bing.com%2FPassport.aspx%3Frequrl%3Dhttp%253a%252f%252fwww.bing.com%252f&lc=1033&id=264960

Once at that site when using chrome the only two functions I can get to work properly are

```
@browser.title
@browser.html
```

are the only functions that work properly. When I try

```
@browser.links.size
@browser.button[0].flash
@browser.button[0].click
```

I get

Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnhandledError:

Using :id etc to reference the objects doesn't work either.

However IE and Firefox can interact with the site fine.

If you need code or clarification let me know, but basically I can't get chrome to interact with that log in site. (Other sites work just fine on chrome)

Comment: This looks like a ChromeDriver bug, and should be raised against the ChromeDriver project.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install the ChomeDriver, which involves downloading the binary and putting it on your PATH. See: http://watirwebdriver.com/chrome/

This site works perfectly for me in Chrome.

Eg.

```
$irb
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > require 'watir-webdriver'
 => true 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :002 > b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
 => #<Watir::Browser:0x6c6e06ba1a564e50 url="about:blank" title="about:blank"> 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :003 > b.goto "https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=11&ct=1314808262&rver=6.0.5286.0&wp=MBI&wreply=http:%2F%2Fwww.bing.com%2FPassport.aspx%3Frequrl%3Dhttp%253a%252f%252fwww.bing.com%252f&lc=1033&id=264960"
 => "https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=11&ct=1314808262&rver=6.0.5286.0&wp=MBI&wreply=http:%2F%2Fwww.bing.com%2FPassport.aspx%3Frequrl%3Dhttp%253a%252f%252fwww.bing.com%252f&lc=1033&id=264960" 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :004 > b.title
 => "Welcome to Windows Live" 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :005 > b.html
 => "<!-- ServerInfo: BAYIDSLGN1M37 2011.07.22.19.28.58...
```

Comment: I have the chrome driver and have been using Chrome for a while with webdriver. I checked again and it still won't work for me. I can get to the site, and again the "b.title" and "b.html" are the only functions that work. But if I try "b.button(:id, "i0010").click (or anything else) I get the error.

Comment: I see. I get the same error as you. Is there a specific reason you need to use Chrome over Firefox or IE?

Comment: Nope, was just wondering if anyone had run into this as well and if it truly was a bug. Thanks for looking into it! I'll submit a bug report to the ChromeDriver project